# Salesforce debug log VFRemoting filtering

Tags: debugging, salesforce, apex

We are currently using a managed package that generate multiple VFRemoting Operations, each operation has an extensive number of managed package lines with no useful information, I would like to be able to view only the salesforce activities. like Approval processes, trigger, Validation rules, workflows and filter all the managed package lines, is their anyway to achieve that.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Modify your debug logs levels, set the items you want to see (Validation, Apex Code, etc) DEBUG set the others to None